# Word shows trays that are not installed with an exclamation mark

Tags: .net, printing, ms-word, tray

In my project, I'm trying to reach trays of the installed printers and successfully doing it. If some paper sources of the selected printer are not installed I don't show them in the paper source combo. In the mean time, Word also don't show them in the print dialog - paper/quality tab. But when Word shows non-installed trays with an exclamation mark, my combo also shows them (without any mark of course). Why does Word show them and what is the meaning of that exclamation mark? And how can I avoid those trays?

- I'm using System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSource to get trays.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you're getting inconsistent driver behavior. What type of printer are you using?

Comment: There are two printers. One is HP4250 laser, the other one is also laser but i don't know which model.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Word are you using and can you also tell the version of the driver?

Normally print  drivers which use the Microsoft Unidrv framework has an option to show a yellow exclamation mark for settings that have constraints. This is applicable for trays that are not installed. You can resolve the Tray constraints by going to your driver properties (Printers and Faxes folder --> Driver Properties --> Device Settings) and set the tray to installed.

You cant really avoid those trays since the driver mostly reports all the trays back to the application when it requests for trays. One way you can find out what trays are installed and what are not is by checking the registry.

Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers((queue- name))\PrinterDriverData
Key name in dir: FeatureKeyword

Hope this helps. If so, (+1) :)